# Make VSCode default to "All Files" rather than Plaintext for unrecognized file types

Tags: visual-studio-code, file-type

I'm working on a project with a bunch of nonstandard file extensions. When I try to save them VSCode defaults to "Plaintext" and sticks an extra ".txt" on their filenames unless I manually select "All Files" as the type in the save dialogue every time. How can I work around this undesirable behavior?